# Data Hashing vs Merkle Trees (account compression) on Solana. Which is better for compressing a large data sample?

Tags: solana-program, hashing

We are using Solana's hash function: (https://docs.rs/solana-program/1.15.2/solana_program/hash/struct.Hash.html) to compress a large data sample (only strings) it takes thousands of bytes down to a single pubkey.

Is there a reason or benefit to using a merkle tree(s) as described in Solana's Concurrent Merkle Tree Whitepaper (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BOpa5OFmara50fTvL0VIVYjtg-qzHCVc/view) rather than just hashing the data to a single pubkey. Potentially a security reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason is using tree is more beneficial when it comes to update the leaf nodes. from the whitepaper that you shared:

> Realistically, there can be multiple requests to modify leaf nodes of
> a tree that use the same root node as reference.

it also shows an image:

[image]

if X10 leaf node needs to be changed we update only 3 more nodes. Its time complexity is 0(LogN) in base2 in this case. Hashing itself is a very expensive operation.